# mat-menu-item is not clickable with protractor e2e tests

Tags: angular, angular-material, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm using `mat-menu` from angular/material:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item id = "item1">Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item id = "item2">Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

In the Page Object `po.ts`, I'm searching for the first button:

```
getMenuButton() {
    return element(by.buttonText('Menu'));
}

getItem1Button() {
    return element(by.id('item1'));
}
```

In the .spec files, I'm trying to click on the first button:

```
po.getMenuButton().click();
expect(get.getItem1Button().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
po.getItem1Button().click();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
- Failed: unknown error: Element <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-menu-item
ng-tns-c1-0 ng-star-inserted" mat-menu-item="" role="menuitem" tabindex="0"
ng-reflect-router-link="item1" id="item1" aria-disabled="false">...</button>
is not clickable at point (328, 42). Other element would receive the click:
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" dir="ltr" style="pointer-events: auto;
top: 10px; right: 16px;">...</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

By looking at https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9755 and https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10140 it seems as if the issue sits in chrome. My current solution to this problem is to click on the element by executing a script through the webdriver.

```
clickLogoutButton() {
    browser.executeScript(`
        const button = document.querySelector(
            'button[data-menu-item-named="logout"]'
        );

        button.click();`
    );
}

performLogout() {
    this.clickUserMenuTriggerButton();

    this.clickLogoutButton();
}
```

Comment: You're right: I also found it out (issue 10140 is mine). I just tested your workaround: perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you get "is not clickable at point" error in protractor, the element you are trying to click is probably hidden.

Before triggering a click on the menu button, make sure the menu main button is clicked and the element is visible.

Therefore, click the parent element before clicking the `#item1` button.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id="myMenu">Menu</button>
```

Test:

```
element(by.id('myMenu')).click();
po.getItem1Button().click();
```

Comment: Can you try adding `browser.sleep(500)` between the clicks?

Comment: I'm first triggering a click on the main menu button, then test if the `item1`is visible, then click it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by menu items that were not visible due to scrolling (overflow.)

I solved it by changing scrollTop to 0:

`browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = 0;", element(by.css('.mat-select-panel')));`

I also had to add `browser.sleep(500);` to overcome dialog popup animation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exact issue, and I was able to solve this by replacing `BrowserAnimationsModule` with `NoopAnimationsModule`. This slightly modifies your code under test, but I can live with that. I added a new flag to my environment, and added the following line to my `AppModule` imports array:

```
environment.testing ? NoopAnimationsModule : BrowserAnimationsModule
```